# Servlet Listener is not setting up the attribute in ContextListener

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to create a JDBC Connection sub type object at the time of deployment. So, There is a Listener class where the Connection sub type object is being created and it is been setting up in context attribute named as mycon. But, when the time of getting the attribute in servlet class, it returns only NULL value. Here my code snippets, index.html: `<a href="servlet2">Fetch Data</a>`  && MyListener class:

```
package FetchData;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            String s1="Kalidass";
            //load the Mysql Driver class
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");

            ServletContext sc=ctx.getServletContext();
            sc.setAttribute("mycon", con);
            sc.setAttribute("name",s1);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

My Servlet Class:

```
package FetchData;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Extract
 */
/*@WebServlet("/Extract")*/
public class Extract extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Extract() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
        out.print("<b>"+sc+"</b>");
        String name=(String)sc.getAttribute("name");
        out.print("<b>"+name+"</b>");
        try{

            Connection conn=(Connection)sc.getAttribute("mycon");
            ///String name=(String)sc.getAttribute("name");
            out.print(conn);
            //out.print(name);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

&& web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<listener>
<listener-class>FetchData.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>serv1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>FetchData.Extract</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>serv1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When i get an attribute value in my servlet class what attribute is being setting up in MyListener class is returns only NULL. Any one please help me out from this. Thanks...

Comment: Can't see any obvious issues. Do you get null for the "name" attribute?

Comment: Yes for name as well as Connection sub type object reference attribute also. Initially i have coded till data retrieval through Print Writer Stream object, I display the result in the page but it shows only empty page. So, I tried to display the Connection sub type object reference attribute, it shows only NULL value but it displays an hash code of servlet context object.

Comment: I rigged up a test on the latest WebSphere Liberty driver where a ServletContextListener sets an attribute and a servlet reads it, very similar to your code, and it works fine. I notice in your ServletContextListener you will not set any attributes if getConnection throws an exception - is that a possibility here? (although I assume you would have noticed the stack in the logs). If that is not the case what product are you running the test on?